# Active Directory SSSD - Change Password on GDM login Screen

Tags: gdm, active-directory, sddm, sssd

Looking to see if I can expand the capabilities of the SSSD/AD system with GDM, or SDDM.

We want users to be able to change their Active Directory password through our Ubuntu machines, if their password expires through our AD.

Is this possible?